# wordpress how to upload files to ftp server

Tags: wordpress, ftp

When I upload files from backend or frontend I want those files to be uploaded on another server.
The other server is hosted on time4vps.com (Storage Server)

I had found this code but looks like it doesn't work: https://github.com/pontusab/wp-ftp-media-library
And this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-with-ftp/

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "looks like it doesn't work"? What are the problems you have? This plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-with-ftp/ seems to be exactly what you need. You have to enter your FTP credentials where you want your images to be uploaded.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
I had installed the plugin, added the details on the setting tab.
When I upload a file it shows this: https://prnt.sc/sowsf1
The same thing happens when I upload files from the frontend.( https://prnt.sc/sowvvn WP User frontend)
Looks like its stacking for an unknown reason and showing this error: https://prnt.sc/sowwji

Comment: It seems to be a problem with permissions. What permissions (read / write / execute) have you set for the upload folder? Maybe wordpress is not allowed to get access because the folder is set to read only and the write permission is missing. You can simply change it with a FTP software and right click the folder to change settings.

Comment: I use webmin.
I had installed apache server and made an ftp user: https://prnt.sc/sox24h
the permissions I have for the folder is: https://prnt.sc/sox328

Comment: Did you try click the checkbox in the permissons -> "Others - Write" which is currently missing?

Comment: Clicked the checkbox, perms went to 777 but I have the same problem.

Comment: Still getting the Error 200 HTTP Error ? This normaly is caused by perms problems. But if it is 777 now, it is not a problem of your target folder... Maybe double check your ftp credentials or try uploading a really small file.. ?

Comment: Still getting 200 HTTP Error.
If i use filezilla the file uploads normally.

The fun fact is when I upload from backend its tucked as I said before but if you refresh the page the file is uploaded, it shows me the file URL on remote storage server but it shows error 404 if you click on it and after 5minutes (about) by magic the file is there....

Comment: I think you should get in contact with the plugin author or check there support forum. We do not know the code of your plugin or could help, only if there is someone using exactly this plugin and having the same issue...

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your kind help :)

One more question, do you think there is an alternative way to reach the target?
I guess you have understood what I want to do.

Comment: I think CDN is the way to go... If you are not using a very popular image hoster (there are plugins for them https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) you will have to take some effort. But this is a good start https://wordpress.org/plugins/cdn-enabler/  You can also add external images to your image librar, but I think you want to upload from the media library, and it should upload (and load from) another server. Maybe get a look into CDN, which is there for this use case.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with Another plugin :)